# Silly suggestions SASS VS Code

Tags: sass, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I don't want to turn suggestions off altogether. I just want them to not be this dumb. How do I tell VS Code to stop doing this when *editing SASS*? It is really weird because I don't find things like variable names being suggested. Current functionality yields only these type of annoyances, and I've got the useful `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false` already, which greatly improved experiences when editing JS and HTML, JSON and more. But, here, this setting seems ignored.
Perhaps the answer I'm looking for is to the question, "Where are these `red($color)` suggestions coming from and how do I turn that off?"

BTW, my example with the string value "red" is something I do just to make it really obvious my SASS is being compiled/watched.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of suggestions you can turn off in settings.  For example:

`Editor > Suggest: Show Colors` is true by default, disabling it you won't get those color suggestions anymore.

Under `Editor > Suggest: ...` there are lots more you might want to disable.

Comment: I just can't find which one is responsible for these particular suggestions when editing SASS and was hoping somebody had dealt with this before. Maybe it is an Emmet installed add-on?